# Foreign key constraint fails while using Spring Data

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data to access my MySQL database with following entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Category category;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_category")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

Now I try to use my `Controller` to delete `Product`

```
@RequestMapping(path="/remove/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String removeProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return productService.removeProduct(id);
    }

public String removeProduct(Long productID) {
        try {
            productRepository.delete(productID);
            return "OK";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

Now, for example if there are 3 `Products` with `Category` A and 1 with `Category` B, I can remove the one with `Category` B. But if I try to remove any other one, I got

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`product_db`.`tbl_product`, CONSTRAINT `FKfq7110lh85cseoy13cgni7pet`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_category` (`id`))

Comment: Well, that's quite of expected, since you **explicitly** configure the ManyToOne association to cascade **all** operations. So when JPA deletes a product, it also tried to delete its category, which doesn't make any sense, since **other** products use that category. Remove that cascade option. Only use non-default options if you fully understand them.

Comment: You must persist Category before you persist product. Show us the code of your "add" method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the cascading that you are applying by `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.

So, whenever you delete any product, JPA deletes the category id too. It works well if that category is not associated with any other product(which is what is happening in your second case). But if the category is associated with any other product then the foreign key constraint fails stating that category which you are trying to delete is associated with other product.

You should be very careful while mentioning cascade type. By default cascade mode is NONE but you can give different strategies like UPDATE,  PERSIST etc. based upon your requirement